# Exclude empty array fields - but include documents missing the field - in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to run a query against elasticsearch that will find documents where one of the following conditions applies:

- The document is missing the given field (`tags`) OR
- The document has the value `foo` as an element of the `tags` array

The problem is that my current query will return documents that have a `tags` field where the value is an empty array. Presumably this is because elasticsearch is treating an empty array as the same thing as not having the field at all. Here's the full query I'm running that's returning the bad results:

```
{
    "from": 0, 
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "exists": {
                                "field": "_rankings.public"
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "or": [
                                {
                                    "missing": {
                                        "existence": true, 
                                        "field": "tags", 
                                        "null_value": false
                                    }
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "terms": {
                                        "execution": "or", 
                                        "tags": [
                                            "foo"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }, 
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            }
        }
    }, 
    "size": 10000, 
    "sort": [
        {
            "_rankings.public": {
                "ignore_unmapped": true, 
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve this so easily "out-of-the-box" for the reason you already mentioned: there's no difference between an empty array and a field (corresponding to that array) with no values in it.

Your only option might be to use a "null_value" for that "tags" field and, if you have any control over the data that goes into your documents, to treat a "[]" array as a '["_your_null_value_of_choice_"]'. And in your query to change `"null_value": false` to `true`.

Comment: Why wouldn't setting `null_value: false` exclude all docs with null values, including empty arrays? It seems like it should from the missing filter docs: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-missing-filter.html

Comment: "null_value" attribute for "missing" filter is to tell ES to consider the "null_value" field set for a field (via mappings) to be considered as a missing field. In the example I gave, if you put  `"tags": ["_your_null_value_of_choice_"]` and set `"null_value": true` will consider that document to have an array with a null in it. If you put `"null_value": false`, the document will not be considered because ES doesn't know that the value you put in there is a null. So, "null_value" attribute is not used for what you believe it should be used for, it's linked with "null_value" set for a field.